# Using chunk in json, requests to get large data into python

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, chunking

I am trying to get a large data into python using API. But I am not being able to get the entire data. The request is allowing only first 1000 lines to be retrieved.

```
r = requests.get("https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/6zsd-86xi.json")

json=r.json()
df=pd.DataFrame(json)
df.drop(df.columns[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]], axis=1, inplace=True) #dropping some columns
df.shape
```

Output is

```
(1000,22)
```

The website contains almost 6 million data points. Yet only 1000 are retrieved. How do I get around this? Is chunking right option? Can someone please help me with the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to paginate through the results to get the entire dataset. Most APIs will limit the amount of results returned in a single request. According to the [Socrata docs](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/paging.html) you need to add `$limit` and `$offset` parameters to the request url.

For example, for the first page of results you would start with -
`https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/6zsd-86xi.json?$limit=1000&$offset=0`

Then for the next page you would just increment the offset -
`https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/6zsd-86xi.json?$limit=1000&$offset=1000`

Continue incrementing until you have the entire dataset.